# Can I say two "concepts are contradiction"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to tell a person that you can't accept two different concepts at one time because one suggests you to be A and the other suggests you to be B.

Can I simply say "The two concepts are contradiction(s)" or "The two concepts are a pair of contradiction(s)"?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should say:

> The two concepts are **contradictory**.

[***contradictory***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/contradictory) sense 1:

> *adjective*
>   1) involving a contradiction; inconsistent (also ) ˌcontraˈdictive

The example sentences should be helpful.

Comment: thanks, just wondering, what does `sense` mean in your `sense 1`?

Comment: It means the definition number listed on the linked dictionary page.

Comment: You could also say "The two concepts contradict each other."

Comment: the two of them together make one contradiction, not a pair.

Comment: +1. To be even more explicit, you can say that they are *mutually contradictory* (meaning that each one contradicts the other).